# EditText Crash while using paste : Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 98, -81

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am using EditText in my app, I see during copy/paste operations sometimes it crashes the app. Unfortunately I couldn't replicate the error or never encountered it but there are good number of people experiencing it.

I am attaching the Log :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 98, -81
   at android.text.PackedIntVector.deleteAt(PackedIntVector.java:218)
   at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:308)
   at android.text.DynamicLayout.access$000(DynamicLayout.java:41)
   at android.text.DynamicLayout$ChangeWatcher.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:650)
   at android.text.DynamicLayout$ChangeWatcher.onSpanChanged(DynamicLayout.java:679)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1019)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendToSpanWatchers(SpannableStringBuilder.java:601)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:532)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:465)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:38)
   at android.widget.TextView.paste(TextView.java:9130)
   at android.widget.TextView.onTextContextMenuItem(TextView.java:8940)
   at com.paprbit.dcoder.ui.widget.DcoderEditor.onTextContextMenuItem(DcoderEditor.java:881)
   at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.onClick(Editor.java:3047)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4825)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20144)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5537)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
```

Here is my code :

```
 @Override
public boolean onTextContextMenuItem(
        final int id) {
    boolean handled = false;
    switch (id) {
        case CodeNow.ID_UNDO:
            handled = true;
            if (canUndo()) {
                undo();
            }
            break;
        case CodeNow.ID_REDO:
            handled = true;
            if (canRedo()) {
                redo();
            }
            break;

    }
    if (handled) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onTextContextMenuItem(id);
    }

}
```

My xml Code Where i added the edittext

```
<com.paprbit.dcoder.ui.widget.DcoderEditor
                        android:id="@+id/et_code_content"
                        style="?editTextDcoderEditor"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor" />
```

and style for this edittext

```
 <style name="EditTextDcoderEditor">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:selectAllOnFocus">false</item>
    <item name="android:imeOptions">flagNoExtractUi</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:isScrollContainer">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: what `undo` and `redo` methods do ? show the code

Comment: Post your xml for the EditText.

Comment: @RishabhDuttSharma No I'm not using that attribute.

Comment: Please add xml code of your edit text may be it's happening due to your string length .

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain undo redo, is achieved by maintaining a linkedlist. The issue is in the else part i think where call goes to system, which is not being handled by my code.

Comment: @GevariaPurva xml and style both added.

Comment: @SamuelRobert xml and style added, please take a look.

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain , the issue is in 881 line according to the log which is  return super.onTextContextMenuItem(id);

Comment: why don't you just show what is in undo and redo methods ? on the other side try to trim your text for left and right spaces they cause issues sometimes

Comment: What is line 881 of DcoderEditor.java?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice 881 line : return super.onTextContextMenuItem(id);